# FB.Event.subscribe

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I subscribe to [Subscribe Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/) event using [FB.Event.subscribe](http://FB.Event.subscribe)?

I generated subscribe button:

```
<div class="fb-subscribe" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck" data-show-faces="true"
        data-width="450">
```

There is way that I know if the user "subscribe" or "unsubscribe"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Facebook's current documentation, you can't subscribe to that.  You can apply that method to 11 events, but pressing the subscribe button is not one of them.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe there is way to get all user's subscribes?